# How find all $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\cot \left(\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}\right)-\cot(x)>2^n$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How find all $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\cot \left(\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}\right)-\cot(x)>2^n$ for $x \in (0,\pi)$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**
$$f(x,n)=\cot \left(\frac{x}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}}\right)-\cot x-2^n$$
It can be shown that $f''(x,n)>0\;\forall\;x,n$.Now minimum value must be greater than zero.So:
$$f(f'^{-1}(0),n)>0$$ which seems to hold for $n=1,2$ only.

I don't know any better analytical solutions, anyways.